# what is CV_8UC3, SCALAR_BLACK);?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat imgContours(imgThresh.size(), CV_8UC3, SCALAR_BLACK);
                                 ************************
```

what is the purpose of the underlined code and how it works?

Comment: They're `#define`'d constants. Use your IDE's "Go to definition" tool - or use OpenCV's documentation:

Comment: @Dai now i know what CV_8UC3 mean but what does SCALAR_BLACK mean?

Comment: I don't think `SCALAR_BLACK` is defined by OpenCV (it would be CV_-prefixed if it were)

Comment: @kmdreko so what is the purpose of it?

Comment: That parameter is for the initial fill value, so its probably a #define or constant for `cv::Scalar(0)` or something similar, you'll have to check the code that has this defined to know for sure

Comment: @kmdreko Thnks for the help everyone. SCALAR_BLACK, Scalar is used to pass pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mat imgContours(imgThresh.size(), CV_8UC3, SCALAR_BLACK);
```

CV_8UC3 is an 8-bit unsigned integer matrix(2D)/image with 3 channels.